# How to receive the product for these two disjoint cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am not sure when to stop the composition for an orbit when I come against a fixed point? Thank You
( 1 4 7 2 )(1 2 8 7 6 3)=?

Comment: If you plug in $1$, the first cycle changes it to $4$ and the second does not touch it, so the product maps $1 \mapsto 4$.

If you plug in $4$, the first cycle maps it to $7$ and the second maps $7$ to $6$, so in total you get $4 \mapsto 8$.

Can you continue?

Comment: (Typo above: "so in total you get $4\mapsto 6$")

Comment: Thanks guys this really helps!